# Can't change color (stroke/fill) in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects

I've created a path in Illustrator and now I want to change the color of the stroke (or fill, it doesn't work on both), but when I chose the new color nothing happens.
Edit: strangely, it changes the stroke color but under the previous color (dont know what to think about that) [image]

Comment: You would be better off by not using the UI layout you are using. For some reason they have chosen a default user interface that all but ensures that you cant know whats going on. In fact you would have figured this out eventually if you had a layout with most panels visible.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Appearance Panel. You may have a fill/stroke applied at the layer. The Properties Panel won't show all appearance settings.

Under Appearance on the Properties Panel.. click the little "..." at the bottom right to open the Appearance Panel.